# Obtain values that match in two different arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

In a service request, I obtain an array with this structure:

```
(
        {
        key = 1;
        val = "Cookies";
    },
        {
        key = 2;
        val = Restaurante;
    },
        {
        key = 22;
        val = "Cereals";
    },
        {
        key = 16;
        val = "Shirts";
    }
```

In a second request, I obtain another array of values that are related to the array of the first request:

```
▿ Optional<NSArray>
  ▿ some : 5 elements
    - 0 : 1
    - 1 : 2
    - 2 : 5
    - 3 : 19
    - 4 : 20
```

What I need is to show in a tableView the text of the first array whose keys I obtain in the second array, how could I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you parse your array to get custom struct, and not only manage `NSArray` or `Array`, might be interesting to do so.

Comment: Your first and second arrays don't actually seem to share any keys.

Comment: Can you post the code where you manage both requests decoding?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you obtain that types of arrays

```
struct ArrayObject {
    let key: Int
    let value: String
}

let objectArray: [ArrayObject] = []
let keysArray: [Int] = []
```

Then you need to use filter to determine what keys are contains in second array:

```
// if you need objects
let filteredObjectsResult = objectArray.filter { keysArray.contains($0.key) }

// if you need values only
let filteredValuesResult = filteredObjectsResult.map { $0.value }
```